# Alignment in JMapPane in java Swing ANd Geotools10.X

Tags: java, swing, geotools, jmap

I am having a problem displaying a plot in jmap pane...

i have a application written using **geotools 10** and java **swing**. we are using JMapPane to display shape file map. when a user clicks a plot a new tab is opened and the details of the plots are displayed there. for the first time it works ok but on next click the plot goes out of the window of **JMapPane** and we have to drag the JMapPane to search the plot.

so i want to know how to display a map in JMapPane **center** every time a plot is clicked.

Comment: where is the next click? in a different plot and you would like that plot centered in the pane after that?

Comment: @iant next click will be some different plot. and yes i want that plot to be in the center